# How do I use the terminal SCREEN when chrooted?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, chroot

How do I allow a user to use SCREEN on a chrooted user?

I have tried everything but I keep on failing.

I need the user to be able to use SCREEN when they are logged in bash as a chrooted user.

Comment: The chrooted user must have enough access to open a new pty, also your question needs more info, do you use any extra security on your system (grsec, selinux, other)?

Answer (score 5):

SCREEN probably needs *devpts*, the pseudo-terminal filesystem, to be mounted on `/dev/pts` inside the chroot.

```
mount -t devpts none "$rootpath/dev/pts" -o ptmxmode=0666,newinstance

ln -fs "pts/ptmx" "$rootpath/dev/ptmx"
```

(The `newinstance` flag is optional; it gives the user a completely separate pty list, preventing them from knowing what other users are logged in.)

Comment: Do I do that on the root user?

Comment: @MuktadirMiah: Yes, and you do that for every user's chroot.  (You can automate it with `pam_exec`.)

Comment: "I ran "mount -t devpts none "/home/jail/dev/pts" -o ptmxmode=0666,newinstance" I get the error "mount: mount point /home/jail/dev/pts does not exist" I used this tutorial to chroot the user: http://dharmitshah.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/sftp-server-configuration-with-chroot.html

Comment: If the mountpoint does not exist, **create it.** With `mkdir`.

Comment: I have done it but still I get "-su: screen: command not found" on the chrooted user.

Comment: Then copy `screen` and its files into the chroot... (Tip: Next time, please mention the error message sooner.)

Comment: I am now getting error "screen: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then copy the libraries into the chroot.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Run `ldd /usr/bin/screen`, then copy all files listed...

Answer (score 1):

In out-of-stock Ubuntu-14.04 this also can be achieved with one "mount" and one "chmod".

Here is `/mnt/old` is chroot's target directory (new "root"). 
Also assumed user `user` belongs to group of `/mnt/old/run` directory (will be a `/run` in chroot-ed environment).

`sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/old/dev/pts
sudo chmod g+w /mnt/old/run
sudo chroot --userspec=user:user /mnt/old
screen`

Caveats: Not sure if sharing of `/dev/pts` is really a good idea from security perspective, and I would *not* recommend this method if security is of concern.